# I cant cmake opencv for java in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: java, opencv, cmake

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Rey.png)Can you help me for my problem. Opencv for Java in Ubuntu linux

Im trying to get the jar and the .so file (.dll equivalent in windows).

In windows, i got jar and the dll in just installing opencv, but in linux i spend a lot of time to learn how to cmake opencv and i can't get it working. Can someone give me a step by step process with picture on how to do it properly. Because the instruction in the opencv site installation instruction for linux doesn't help me, maybe because i don't know how to do cmake properly.

Comment: "Because the instruction in the opencv site installation instruction for linux doesn't help me, maybe because I don't know how to do cmake properly." - Yes, it could be the case. But we cannot help you in fixing your steps without knowing what **exactly** have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the thing that you already tried. 
You can try this [bash script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh) if any luck!

Comment: This looks more suitable for a **comment** to the question, not an **answer** to it.